# Unity - Trying to Calculate In-Game Time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I wrote a day-night cycle script the other day and I have the sun/moon cycle working (its a really rough script, not perfect yet) but one of the other things I wanted to do was to be able to calculate the current time inside the game working off of that day/night cycle.

I have a ticker that is working so far but it is not scaling correctly to the percentage of the day.

Can anyone help me out with this because I think this is beyond my skillset with maths right now.

Basically I just want to solve the current time of day as relative to the % we are moving through the day/night cycle.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class DayNightCycle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static DayNightCycle instance;

    public Light sun, moon;
    public float secondsInFullDay = 3600f;
    
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float currentTimeOfDay = 0f;

    [HideInInspector]
    public float timeMultiplier = 1f;

    float sunInitialIntensity;

    public Camera mainCam;
    public Material skyboxDay, skyBoxNight;

    public float gameTime;
    public float fSeconds;

    public int totalSeconds, iSeconds, minutes, hours, days;
    public int currentSecond, currentMinute, currentHour, currentDay;

    public float previousTime;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        sunInitialIntensity = sun.intensity;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateSun();

        currentTimeOfDay += (Time.deltaTime / secondsInFullDay) * timeMultiplier;

        if (currentTimeOfDay >= 1)
        {
            currentTimeOfDay = 0;
        }

        gameTime += Time.deltaTime;

        // seconds / total seconds = percentage
        // percentage * seconds = total seconds
        // seconds = total seconds * percentage

        totalSeconds = (int)gameTime;

        fSeconds = (secondsInFullDay * currentTimeOfDay);

        currentSecond = (int)fSeconds;

        if (currentSecond >= 60)
            IncrementMinutes();

        if (currentMinute >= 60)
            IncrementHours();

        if (currentHour >= 24)
            IncrementDays();

        previousTime = (int)gameTime;
    }

    void UpdateSun()
    {
        sun.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler((currentTimeOfDay * 360f) - 90, 170, 0);
        moon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler((currentTimeOfDay * 360f) - 90, 170, 0);

        float intensityMultiplier = 1f;
        float moonIntensityMult = 0.025f;

        if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.23f || currentTimeOfDay >= 0.75f)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyBoxNight;
            intensityMultiplier = 0f;
            moonIntensityMult = 0.025f;
        }
        else if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.25f)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyBoxNight;
            intensityMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01((currentTimeOfDay - 0.23f) * (1 / 0.02f));
            moonIntensityMult = 0f;
        }
        else if (currentTimeOfDay >= 0.73f)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxDay;
            
            intensityMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01(1 - ((currentTimeOfDay - 0.73f) * (1 / 0.02f)));
            moonIntensityMult = 0f;
        }

        sun.intensity = sunInitialIntensity * intensityMultiplier;
        moon.intensity = moonIntensityMult;
    }

    public float GetTimeOfDayInSeconds
    {
        get { return currentTimeOfDay; }
        set { return; }
    }

    void IncrementMinutes()
    {
        currentMinute++;
        currentSecond = 0;
    }

    void IncrementHours()
    {
        currentHour++;
        currentSecond = 0;
        currentMinute = 0;
    }

    void IncrementDays()
    {
        currentDay++;
        currentSecond = 0;
        currentMinute = 0;
        currentHour = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for all the extra unused vars, they're remnants from each time I've tried to iterate through solving my problem.  I usually write out a bunch of code and then go back and try to streamline it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I got it to where it is correctly synched now with the day/night cycle I just need to clean this code up quite a bit.  Note: The way I'm increasing days will start to fail if you use an exceptionally long in game day I think.  The boolean might work but it might also give you a new day before the end of the current day.  I was testing this on a 3600 second long day.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class DayNightCycle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static DayNightCycle instance;

    public Light sun, moon;
    public float secondsInFullDay = 3600f;
    
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float currentTimeOfDay = 0f;

    [HideInInspector]
    public float timeMultiplier = 1f;

    float sunInitialIntensity;

    public Material skyboxDay, skyBoxNight;

    public double elapsedRealTime;

    public float secondsPerDayMultiplier;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speedOfGameSecond, speedOfGameMinute, speedOfGameHour, speedOfGameDay;

    [SerializeField]
    private float currentGameSecond, currentGameMinute, currentGameHour, currentGameDay;

    private bool stopIncrementingDay;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speedOfGameSecond = secondsInFullDay / 24 / 60 / 60;
        speedOfGameMinute = secondsInFullDay / 24 / 60;
        speedOfGameHour = secondsInFullDay / 24;
        speedOfGameDay = secondsInFullDay;

        
        sunInitialIntensity = sun.intensity;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateSun();

        currentTimeOfDay += (Time.deltaTime / secondsInFullDay) * timeMultiplier;

        if (currentTimeOfDay >= 1)
        {
            currentTimeOfDay = 0;
        }

        secondsPerDayMultiplier = currentTimeOfDay * secondsInFullDay;

        // seconds / total seconds = percentage
        // percentage * seconds = total seconds
        // seconds = total seconds * percentage

        currentGameSecond = secondsPerDayMultiplier / speedOfGameSecond;

        currentGameMinute = secondsPerDayMultiplier / speedOfGameMinute;
       
        currentGameHour = secondsPerDayMultiplier / speedOfGameHour;

        if(!stopIncrementingDay && currentGameHour >= 23.999)
        {
            IncrementDay();
            stopIncrementingDay = true;
        } else if(currentGameHour <= 23.999)
        {
            stopIncrementingDay = false;
        }

        elapsedRealTime += Time.deltaTime;
        previousTime = Time.deltaTime;

    }

    void UpdateSun()
    {
        sun.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler((currentTimeOfDay * 360f) - 90, 170, 0);
        moon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler((currentTimeOfDay * 360f) - 90, 170, 0);

        float intensityMultiplier = 1f;
        float moonIntensityMult = 0.025f;

        if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.23f || currentTimeOfDay >= 0.85f)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyBoxNight;
            intensityMultiplier = 0f;
            moonIntensityMult = 0.025f;
        }
        else if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.25f)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyBoxNight;
            intensityMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01((currentTimeOfDay - 0.23f) * (1 / 0.02f));
            moonIntensityMult = 0f;
        }
        else if (currentTimeOfDay >= 0.83f)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxDay;
            
            intensityMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01(1 - ((currentTimeOfDay - 0.83f) * (1 / 0.02f)));
            moonIntensityMult = 0f;
        }

        sun.intensity = sunInitialIntensity * intensityMultiplier;
        moon.intensity = moonIntensityMult;
    }

    public float GetTimeOfDayPercent
    {
        get { return currentTimeOfDay; }
        set { return; }
    }

    public float GetSecondsPerDay()
    {
        return secondsInFullDay;
    }

    private void IncrementDay()
    {
        currentGameSecond = 0;
        currentGameMinute = 0;
        currentGameHour = 0;
        currentGameDay++;
    }

    public void GetTimeOfDay()
    {
        // now to work on this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think keeping track of second, minute hour and increment each separtedly is not the right approach. You need to now the scale or proprotion factor between your game time and the real time, and handle the one time variable at once.

Find this trial function to obtain the sacaled time I think you need.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class DayNightCycle : MonoBehaviour {

    // This  is public to check with manual input if the obtained time is the one we expect. 
    // In the real method, this should not exist and should be calculated with the elapsed time of the game, 
    // commented belowin the getGameTime(int secodsDayDurationInGame) method
    public double elapsedRealTime; 

    float startingGameTime;
    DateTime startingGameDate;

    private void Start() {
        startingGameTime = Time.time;
        startingGameDate = DateTime.Now; // choose the starting date you like
    }

    private float secondsOfARealDay = 24 * 60 * 60;

    DateTime getGameTime(int secodsDayDurationInGame) {
        float scaledElapsedSecondInGame = secondsOfARealDay / secodsDayDurationInGame; // second equivalent in your game 
        //float elapsedRealTime = Time.time - startingGameTime; // uncomment to calculate with elapsed real time.
        DateTime gateDateTime = startingGameDate.AddSeconds(elapsedRealTime * scaledElapsedSecondInGame);

        return gateDateTime;
    }

    void OnMouseDown() { // this makes the cube clickable
        Debug.LogError(getGameTime(3600).ToString());
    }
}
```

You can try it making a cube clickable to print the output when you update the elapsed time in the public variable.
It is for 3600 second day in your game, but if you whant another game day duration you can just make that variabel puclic and try.

[image]

Important to have a collider, if not, cube wont be clickable. However It is added by default when you add the primitive right click in the scene -> 3D Object -> Cube.

You can check for example that if you add 3600 to the elapsed time public variable, and you click the cube you obtain tomorrows date in the console.

[image]

When you check the function works according to your needs you can uncomment the line `//float elapsedRealTime = Time.time - startingGameTime;` to use the real time elapsed or the one you wish for the date calculation.

Comment: This is an interesting way to go about it.

Comment: So this does help me compute a game time that seems proportional correctly.  The issue is that like because I'm playing at 5:30 PM its starting at 5:30 PM when it should be started at 00:01.

Comment: I think I just got it working off your model though!  Bah nevermind it's calculating a full day has passed before the sun/moon cycle has gone from 0 to 1.